# AWS Cognito: How should I handle PasswordResetRequiredException

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have clicked "Reset Password" in Cognito and now when I login I get "`PasswordResetRequiredException`", how should I handle this? I cant find anything in the docs that tell me what should I do?

Answer (score 4):

check this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-using-import-tool-password-reset.html

you need to call ForgotPassword()...

Comment: The problem here is that when you click "Reset Password" on Cognito, it sends an email with a verification code to the user. And when you call forgotPassword(), it sends another verification code by email. So the user get 2 emails with 2 differents code. Not a big deal though, but not the best user experience, in my opinion. Is there a way to avoid having 2 emails?

Answer (score 4):

I figured out the exact way that you can handle this on (onFailure) callback:

```
// Create a cognito user instance
const cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);
// Trigger to authenticate the user
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, { 
  onFailure: function(err) {
    if (err.code == "PasswordResetRequiredException") {
      // Confirm user data
      cognitoUser.confirmPassword(
        "", // Put your verification code here
        "", // Here is your new password
        {
          onSuccess: result => {
            // Everything worked as expected
          },
          onFailure: err => {
            // Trigger failure
          }
        }
      );
    } else {
      // Trigger failure
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the specific user should have had an email or sms sent to them (if their email or phone number had been verified). In this email there should be a code which you can use with ConfirmForgotPassword

Answer (score 0):

You would have to implement the newPasswordRequired callback for authenticateUser such as below:

```
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess: function (result) {
        // User authentication was successful
    },

    onFailure: function(err) {
        // User authentication was not successful
    },

    mfaRequired: function(codeDeliveryDetails) {
        // MFA is required to complete user authentication.
        // Get the code from user and call
        cognitoUser.sendMFACode(mfaCode, this)
    },

    newPasswordRequired: function(userAttributes, requiredAttributes) {
        // User was signed up by an admin and must provide new
        // password and required attributes, if any, to complete
        // authentication.

        // the api doesn't accept this field back
        delete userAttributes.email_verified;

        // Get these details and call
        cognitoUser.completeNewPasswordChallenge(newPassword, userAttributes, this);
    }
});
```

Comment: I did and it does not go into the callback. I think thats only used for a new account?

Comment: Exactly, that callback "newPasswordRequired" is only for when the user first logs in because it was recently created through the API.What the question is asking is a different flow

Comment: @LeonardoG. - PasswordResetRequiredException is not only on new accounts. The admin can set the "reset password" flag which sends a PasswordResetRequiredException without going to the callback.